# Adobe flex mobile application

Tags: android, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder, flex-mobile

I need to develop wallpaper app using adobe flex with adobe flash builder so that I need help after I complete user interface and I downloaded wallpaper manager native cod please help me where i write native cods to set image as wallpaper on the device .tnx!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is setting a local image file to your device wallpaper right?

If yes, you can download [on this page](http://flashvisions.com/how-to-set-wallpaper-on-android-with-adobe-air/) an ANE that should be doing what you want (I haven't tested it myself though), I guess it's the same one you were talking about when mentionning Wallpaper Manager.

Using it simply means getting an instance of the manager and calling one of the following functions:

```
var manager:WallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance();
if (manager.isSupported())
{
    manager.setWallpaperFromPath(IMAGE-NATIVE-PATH); // if using a native path of a image on device
    manager.SetWallpaperFromBitmapData(BITMAPDATA); // if using an actionscript Bitmapdata object
}
```